# How to reduce sample data to a smaller scale?

Tags: group-differences, population, scales, model-comparison

In statistics let's say for a specific city (call it "City A") 1000 people die of driving related accidents annually. The city has a population of 2.7 million people. In another city, "City B" 3000 people die annually from driving related accidents but 7.3 million people live in City B. How could I provide a proper statistical comparison to prove which city has better drivers, while taking respect to the difference in population?

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it: For A the annual car death rate is $\frac{1000}{2700000} = 0.00037$, i.e. 37 out of 100'000 anually. For city B it's $\frac{3000}{7300000} = 0.00041$, i.e. 41 out of 100'000 anually.

So purely from a car death rate perspective, city A is better (lower death rate). However, I wouldn't go as far as concluding automatically that city B drivers are worse. There could be many factors, e.g. less lights on road, more rainy weather or a thousand other things that influence the rate from above.

As long as there is not more info about city A or city B and their populations this is the best you can do.